# Trying to make ajax call with phonegap and zepto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cordova

I am new to phonegap and and trying to build a basic app that is pulling data from a rails app using ajax. Here are the relevant files...

```
#www/index.html
    <body>
    <h1>Task List</h1>
    <div class="page current" id="tasks">
      <header>
        <h1>Open Tasks</h1>
      </header>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tasks.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

#www/js/tasks.js
function loadTasks() {
  var tasks = $('#tasks ul');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://limitless-chamber-2009.herokuapp.com/tasks.json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i,item){
        tasks.append('<li>'+item.name+'</li>')
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      tasks.append('<li>There was an error loading the tasks');
    }
  });
}

loadTasks();
```

When I loaded index.html in my web browser I get the error "There was an error loading the tasks". I know there are sophisticated ways to debug this, but I'm a js and ajax noob, so not sure what to check, but I am open to suggestions. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work in a Cordova/PhoneGap app, try setting your whitelist.

In `./www/config.xml`, set your whitelist to:

`<access origin="limitless-chamber-2009.herokuapp.com" />`

or even

`<access origin="*" />`

To make this work in your web browser, you will need to start Chrome with web-security disabled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677/878602

Comment: Also FYI to folks. I was testing this in the browser. Needed to start chrome w/out security "google-chrome  --disable-web-security" for this to work in the browser.